# Is it possible to avoid writing 'dot' each time when calling class method?

Tags: python

Sorry for somewhat unclear question. I'm actually wondering whether it's possible in Python not to mention class name, when you call class's methods iteratively? I mean to write instead of:

```
SomeClass.Fun1()
SomeClass.Fun2()
...
SomeClass.Fun100()
```

Something like:

```
DoWith SomeClass:
    Fun1()
    Fun2()
    ...
    Fun100()
```

?

Comment: Looks like someone is used to Visual Basic!

Comment: True) but more than 10 years ago

Comment: It depends, do the method require an instance to operate off of? For example `def Fun1(self):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several methods to achieve that (`from SomeClass import *`, `locals().update(SomeClass.__dict__())`), but what you're trying is not really logical:

In 90% of cases you're not calling static class methods, but member functions, which need a single *instance* to operate on. You do realize that the first, the `self` argument that you typically see on methods is important, because it gives you access to the instance's namespace. So even in methods, you use `self.my_member` instead of `my_member`. That's an important python concept, and you should not try to avoid it -- there's a difference between the local name space and the attributes of an instance.

What you can do, however, is having a short handle, without any overhead:

```
my_instance = SomeClass() #notice, this is an instance of SomeClass, not the class or type itself
__ = my_instance
```

that can save you a lot of typing. But I prefer clarity over saved typing (hell, `vim` has good autocompletion plugins for Python).

Answer (score 1):

yes, just try `from SomeClass import *` (after moving SomeClass to an other file of course)